# Maximum value of $f(x) = \left|\sqrt{\sin^2 x+2a^2} - \sqrt{2a^2-1-\cos^2 x}\right|\;\;,$ Where $a,x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Calculation of Maximum value of $\displaystyle f(x) = \left|\sqrt{\sin^2 x+2a^2} - \sqrt{2a^2-1-\cos^2 x}\right|\;\;,$ Where $a,x\in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We Can Write It as $f(x) = \left|\sqrt{2a^2-\cos^2 x+1}-\sqrt{2a^2-\cos^2 x-1}\right|$

Now Let $\left(2a^2-\cos^2 x\right) = b\in \mathbb{R}\;,$ Then Expression is $f(b) = \left|\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{b-1}\right|\;,$ where $b\in \mathbb{R}.$

Now How Can I find max. value of $f(b)$

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Note that the value makes sense when $b\geq1$, in this case the function is non-negative, then the module can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

the maximum value of $f(b) = \left|\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{b-1}\right|\;,$ is at $b=1$ which is $\sqrt{2}$ because it is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $g(b)=\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt{b-1}$ where $b\in [2a^2-1,2a^2]$ by using derivative find max and min of $g$ then result follows.